# Rotating a shape about its axis then translating the shape in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to rotate a triangle about its centre (0, 0, 0) and then translate it by (0.5, 0.5, 0). However, no matter if I place the *translateM* command before or after the *rotateM* commands I still get the same result, which is a triangle translated to the said position, rotating (orbiting if you like) about (0, 0, 0). I've looked online and found similar posts, but they don't help. Here is my code:

Note: my triangles are all centred on (0, 0, 0) to begin with.

```
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);

    // *** transform shape before rendering

    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, rx, -1.0f, 0, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);        // rotate

    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, ry, 0, -1.0f, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);        // rotate

    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, rz, 0, 0, -1.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);        // rotate

    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, tx, ty, tz);                         // translate

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0, mvpMatrix, 0);         // world view


    // *** render

    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                 GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                 vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    MyGL20Renderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    MyGL20Renderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably there is something wrong with your matrix multiplication logic. As far as I know, the operation that you want first is multiplied last, so your multiplication order should be first translation and then rotation. Finally, it would be better if we could see your matrix multiplication code either.

Comment: That's what the problem was. I needed to translate first, then rotate, and the order of matrix operands was wrong.